# Convergence of a Sequence fn(x)

Tags: calculus

For every $n \in N ^{*}$, we define the function:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
f_{n}(x): \mathbb{R_+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
f_{n}(x)=\sqrt{1+x \cdot \sqrt{1+(x+1) \cdot \sqrt{1+\cdots+(x+n-1) \cdot \sqrt{1+(x+n)}}}}
\end{array}
$$
a) Prove that for every $x \in R _{+}$:
$$
0<f_n(x)<x+1 $$
b) Prove that the sequence $\left(f_{n}(x)\right)_ {n{\geq 1}}$ is convergent.

My work:

I solved point a by induction and I think it is corect, my question is related to point b) there I have to prove that this sequence $f_n$ is convergent, I tried to prove by reduction to absurdity and take two subsequences and to reach a contradiction that will lead me to the fact that the sequence $f_n$ is convergent but I did not reach a desired result also I tried calculate this limit using limit criteria but I did not know how to apply, any hint would be very useful for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not convergence of a set

Comment: In part $a)$ you should $f_n$ is pointwise bounded; the monotone convergence theorem seems a likely candidate for a convergence proof. You also have $1\le f_n(x)$ for all $n$ and $x\ge0$. We can show that the difference is increasing (as per empirical observations) to show that it is always positive: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)]=\frac{f_n(x+1)+x\cdot f_n'(x+1)}{2\sqrt{1+x\cdot f_n(x+1)}}-f_n'(x)$$But I am unsure how to proceed

Comment: Thank you @FShrike! Yes I was thinking about the monotone convergence theorem but about this difference is increasing i think it is so hard to prove, or maybe I do not Know how to proceed to prove it, I am still searching now in all my books maybe I can find any hint anywhere.

Comment: My comment above was incomplete. The representation: $$f_n(x)=\sqrt{1+x\cdot f_{n-1}(x+1)}$$Could be useful, along with the empirical observation that $f_n$, if it converges, converges via monotonic ascent (again, I don't know how to prove it so this may fail for larger $n$, it's just an observation)

Comment: @FShrike, thank you i will try your method and see if it leads somewhere, thank you so much for your kindness.

Comment: You're welcome. I tried and failed to come up with an answer myself so all I could do was upvote and leave that idea

Comment: @FShrike Do not worry, I will continue to try that night to solve it but if I fail to solve it than I will wait the answers from the professor next week and then I will come back and tell you what is about.

Comment: That is very kind of you, as I am a student myself

Comment: @FShrike Keep in Touch next week promise I will share here the given solution maybe it will help somebody in the future.

Comment: Basing on the recurrence relation if $f_n\ge f_{n-1}$ then $f_{n+1}\ge f_{n}$ . Also if $f_n\le f_{n-1}$ then $f_{n+1}\le f_{n}.$ So it suffices to decide whether $f_0\le f_1$ or $f_0\ge f_1$ and then proceed by induction.

Comment: Clearly the sequence is increasing, without induction method. Observe that on every step you multiply by a quantity greater than $1$ under an appropriate square root.